# How to create a variable in the BSS section in NASM?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I tried to create a variable in the BSS section in NASM:

```
section .bss
    i DD 12345
```

But when trying to create an object file I got the following warning:

```
warning: attempt to initialize memory in BSS section `.bss': ignored
```

Which is understandable I suppose since the BSS section can only contain uninitialized variables. So I attempted the following:

```
section .bss
    i DD 0
```

But I still get the same warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `RESB` and friends. See the [nasm manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.2):

> 3.2.2 RESB and Friends: Declaring Uninitialized Data
>
> RESB, RESW, RESD, RESQ, REST, RESO, RESY and RESZ are designed to be
> used in the BSS section of a module: they declare uninitialized
> storage space. Each takes a single operand, which is the number of
> bytes, words, doublewords or whatever to reserve. As stated in section
> 2.2.7, NASM does not support the MASM/TASM syntax of reserving uninitialized space by writing DW ? or similar things: this is what it
> does instead. The operand to a RESB-type pseudo-instruction is a
> critical expression: see section 3.8.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> buffer:         resb    64              ; reserve 64 bytes
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The resb and Friends in [nasm manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc3.html) is used to reserve specific amount of bytes in the BSS section of the cod: `section .bss`
Notice that this section must be defined in lowercase (bss) in order not to throw the error.
So you may try:

```
section .bss      ; Create the reservation section.
buffer: resb 128  ; Reserve 128 bites of the memory with label "buffer"
```