# x86 procedure (32-bit) only works on certain parts of my code

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, nasm, ld

All genuine solutions/advice/help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

**Here is my basic question:
Why does the 'ClrScreen' procedure at the bottom of my 'Print.asm' file not work in certain locations of my program, but does work in other locations?**

Intended Behavior:
I would like the 'ClrScreen' procedure in 'Print.asm' to work wherever it is called. The reason this procedure is important is because if there's ever an error encountered, I'd like the 'ClrScreen' procedure to execute to clear the Linux Terminal and output an error message.

1.) Clue 1
Write the instruction, 'call ClrScreen' as the first instruction in 'Battle_Chess.asm'. You will see that 'ClrScreen' works as intended right at this location in the program.

2.) Clue 2
Remove the 'call ClrScreen' instruction that we just previously wrote into the beginning of 'Battle_Chess.asm'. Now, write the same instruction 'call ClrScreen' after the instruction 'extern Rows'. 'ClrScreen' works as intended at this location in the program as well.

3.) Clue 3
This is where the conundrum occurs.
Remove the 'call ClrScreen' instruction that we just previously wrote after the 'extern Rows' instruction. Write the instruction 'call ClrScreen' after the last 'mov DWORD [memory address], [immediate value]' instruction but before the 'call GetWinSize' instruction occurs in the 'Battle_Chess.asm' file. Finally, to see the bug remove the semi-colon from the 'mov DWORD [blackQueen + 4], 0x08000000' instruction. Then suddenly 'call ClrScreen' does not work anymore! You can go ahead and clear out all the semi-colons but not the ones for instructions 'mov DWORD [blackQueen + 4], 0x08000000' and 'mov DWORD [blackKing + 4], 0x10000000'. I do not understand how these instructions in particular can affect 'call ClrScreen'.

4.) Clue 4
Remove the 'call ClrScreen' instruction that we just previously wrote before the 'call GetWinSize' instruction. Put the semi-colon back on the two previous instructions that caused the bug mentioned in 'Clue 3'. Write the 'call ClrScreen' instruction after 'call GetWinSize' instruction. Again, 'call ClrScreen' is somehow affected by 'call GetWinSize'.

File: Battle_Chess.asm

```
; Program Author: David Mark Serrano
; Program Name: Battle_Chess
; Date Created: July 12, 2023
; Version: 1.0
; Purpose: To render a textual chessboard on the Linux Terminal for a game of chess against an AI opponent

; Built using file "makefile":
;
; Battle_Chess: Board_Render.o Battle_Chess.o Print.o
;   ld -m elf_i386 -o Battle_Chess Battle_Chess.o Board_Render.o Print.o
;
; Print.o: Print.asm
;   nasm -f elf32 -g -o Print.o Print.asm
;
; Board_Render.o: Board_Render.asm
;   nasm -f elf32 -g -o Board_Render.o Board_Render.asm
;
; Battle_Chess.o: Battle_Chess.asm
;   nasm -f elf32 -g -o Battle_Chess.o Battle_Chess.asm

section .data ; Section for initialized data

; File Descriptors
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
STDERR equ 2

; Strings used in Battle Chess Engine
Terminal_Length db "Columns: ", 0
Minimum_Columns db "150", 0
Terminal_Height db "Rows: ", 0
Minimum_Rows db "45", 0
Error_Message_0x00000001 db "Error 0x00000001: Required terminal dimensions aren't met. Ensure $COLUMNS = 150 and $LINES = 45.", 0xA, 0 

; Chess Pieces
whitePawns db 8
whiteRooks db 8
whiteKnights db 8
whiteBishops db 8
whiteQueen db 8
whiteKing db 8
blackPawns db 8
blackRooks db 8
blackKnights db 8
blackBishops db 8
blackQueen db 8
blackKing db 8


section .text
    global _start

_start:

    nop ; This instruction is used to aid gdb debugger

    ; External references to global procedures defined in 'Board_Render.asm'
    extern GetWinSize

    ; External references to global procedural buffers defined in 'Board_Render.asm'
    extern WinSizeBuff

    ; External references to global procedures defined in 'Print.asm'
    extern PrintString
    extern PrintRows
    extern PrintColumns
    extern ClrScreen

    ; External references to global procedural buffers defined in 'Print.asm'
    extern Columns
    extern Rows

    ; This group of instructions (Line 53 - Line 76) set the initial positions of all game pieces on the Chessboard
    ; Each 8-byte variable is divided into high 32-bits and low 32-bits
    ; Each location in a variable where a bit is set directly corresponds to the game piece actively on that square
;   mov DWORD [whitePawns], 0x0000FF00 ; The White Pawns are actively on { Files A - H; Rank 2  }
;   mov DWORD [whitePawns + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Pawns actively on these squares
;   mov DWORD [whiteRooks], 0x00000081 ; The white Rooks are actively on { File A; Rank 1 } and { File H - Rank 1 }
;   mov DWORD [whiteRooks + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Rooks actively on these squares
;   mov DWORD [whiteKnights], 0x00000042 ; White Knights are actively on { File B; Rank 1 } and { File G; Rank 1 }
;   mov DWORD [whiteKnights + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Knights actively on these squares
;   mov DWORD [whiteBishops], 0x00000024 ; White Bishops are actively on { File C; Rank 1 } { Rank F; File 1 }
;   mov DWORD [whiteBishops + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Bishops actively on these squares
;   mov DWORD [whiteQueen], 0x00000008 ; White Queen is actively on { File D; Rank 1 }
;   mov DWORD [whiteQueen + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Queen on these squares
;   mov DWORD [whiteKing], 0x00000010 ; White King is actively on { File E; Rank 1 }
;   mov DWORD [whiteKing + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White King on these squares
;   mov DWORD [blackPawns], 0x00000000 ; No Black Pawns on these squares
;   mov DWORD [blackPawns + 4], 0x00FF0000 ; Black Pawns are actively on { File A-H; Rank 7 }
;   mov DWORD [blackRooks], 0x00000000 ; No Black Rooks on these squares
;   mov DWORD [blackRooks + 4], 0x81000000 ; Black Rooks are actively on { File A; Rank 8 } { File H; Rank 8 }
;   mov DWORD [blackKnights], 0x00000000 ; No Black Knights on these squares
;   mov DWORD [blackKnights + 4], 0x42000000 ; Black Knights are actively on { File B; Rank 8 } { File G; Rank 8 }
;   mov DWORD [blackBishops], 0x00000000 ; No black Bishops on these squares
;   mov DWORD [blackBishops + 4], 0x24000000 ; Black Bishops are active on { File C; Rank 8 } { File F; Rank 8 }
;   mov DWORD [blackQueen], 0x00000000 ; No Black Queen on these squares
;   mov DWORD [blackQueen + 4], 0x08000000 ; Black Queen is actively on { File D; Rank 8 }
;   mov DWORD [blackKing], 0x00000000 ; No Black King on these squares
;   mov DWORD [blackKing + 4], 0x10000000 ; Black King is actively on { File E; Rank 8 }

    ; This instruction (Line XX) makes a call to procedure 'GWINSZ' in 'Board_Render.asm' file to retrieve dimensions of Linux Terminal
    call GetWinSize

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will print the total $LINES of the current Linux Terminal session
    push Terminal_Length ; Push memory address of string 'Terminal_Length' onto stack
    push 0xA ; Push length of string "Terminal_Length' onto stack
    call PrintString ; Call procedure 'PrintString' from 'Print.asm' file
    call PrintColumns ; Call procedure 'PrintRows' from 'Print.asm' file

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will ensure minimum Linux Terminal length is met, and if not met, the program will terminate
    xor eax, eax ; Clear 'eax' so that it is ready to store ASCII character in 'al'
    xor ecx, ecx ; Clear 'ecx' so that it is to be used as loop counter for 'CheckColumns' procedure
    xor edx, edx ; Clear 'edx' so that is is ready to store ASCII character in 'dl'
    CheckColumns:
    cmp ecx, 0x3 ; Check if 'ecx' has counted entire string "150"
    je CheckColumns.End
    mov al, BYTE [Columns + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Columns' buffer in 'Print.asm' file to 'esi'
    mov dl, BYTE [Minimum_Columns + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Minimum_Columns' in 'Battle_Chess.asm' buffer to 'edi'
    inc ecx ; Increase 'ecx' to update count for indexing into buffers 'Columns' and 'Minimum_Columns'
    cmp al, dl ; Compare ASCII character stored in 'al' with ASCII character stored in 'dl'
    jne Error_0x00000001 ; Jump to label 'Error_0x00000001' if 'al' and 'dl' are not equal
    je CheckColumns ; Repeat loop and jump to label 'Check_Columns' if 'al' and 'dl' are equal
    CheckColumns.End:

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will print the total $COLUMNS of the current Linux Terminal session
    push Terminal_Height ; Push memory address of 'Terminal_Height' onto stack
    push 0x7 ; Push length of string 'Terminal_Height' onto stack 
    call PrintString ; Call procedure 'PrintString' from 'Print.asm' file
    call PrintRows ; Call procedure 'PrintColumns' from 'Print.asm' file

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will ensure minimum Linux Terminal height is met, and if not met, the program will terminate
    xor eax, eax ; Clear 'eax' so that it is ready to store ASCII character in 'al'
    xor ecx, ecx ; Clear 'ecx' so that it is to be used as loop counter for 'CheckColumns' procedure
    xor edx, edx ; Clear 'edx' so that is is ready to store ASCII character in 'dl'
    CheckRows:
    cmp ecx, 0x2 ; Check if 'ecx' has counted entire string "45"
    je CheckRows.End
    mov al, BYTE [Rows + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Columns' buffer in 'Print.asm' file to 'esi'
    mov dl, BYTE [Minimum_Rows + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Minimum_Columns' in 'Battle_Chess.asm' buffer to 'edi'
    inc ecx ; Increase 'ecx' to update count for indexing into buffers 'Columns' and 'Minimum_Columns'
    cmp al, dl ; Compare ASCII character stored in 'al' with ASCII character stored in 'dl'
    jne Error_0x00000001 ; Jump to label 'Error_0x00000001' if 'al' and 'dl' are not equal
    je CheckRows ; Repeat loop and jump to label 'Check_Columns' if 'al' and 'dl' are equal
    CheckRows.End:

    nop ; This instruction is used to aid the GDB debugger

    ; This group of instructions (Line 97 - Line 97) will terminate the program and return code '0' to signal proper execution
    mov eax, 0x1 ; Specify sys_exit syscall
    xor ebx, ebx ; Clear `ebx` register so that it returns exit code 0
    int 0x80 ; Specify Vector Interrupt 128 (Kernel Services / Syscall Dispatcher)

    ; This group of instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will terminate the program and return code '1' to signal error
    Error_0x00000001:
    call ClrScreen ; Clear Linux Terminal so that Error_Message_0x00000001 is printed to 'STDOUT'
    push Error_Message_0x00000001 ; Push memory address of 'Error_Message_0x00000001' onto stack
    push 0x63 ; Push length of 'Error_Message' onto stack (99 characters)
    call PrintString ; Print string 'Error_Message' to STDOUT
    mov eax, 0x1 ; Specify sys_exit syscall 
    mov ebx, 0x1 ; Set 'ebx' register to so that it returns exit code 1
    int 0x80 ; Specify Vector Interrupt 128 (Kernel Services / Syscall Dispatcher)
```

File: Board_Render.asm

```
; Author/Programmer: David Mark Serrano
; Library: Board_Render
; Date Created: 07/21/2023
; Version: 1.0
; Purpose: This is a library with global variables and procedures for rendering the chessboard in the Battle Chess Engine

section .data ; Section for initialized data

; File Descriptor labels for easier referencing
STDIN equ 0 ; fildes 0 is assigned identifier `STDIN`
STDOUT equ 1 ; fildes 1 is assigned identifier `STDOUT`
STDERR equ 2 ; fildes 2 is assigned identifier `STDERR`

; ASCII character definitions for easier referencing
EOL equ 10 ; Linux end-of-line character
SPACECHR equ 32 ; ASCII space character
NULL equ 0 ; ASCII character for null-terminated strings

; Global declarations for 'GWINSZ' procedure and 'winsize_struct' buffer
global GetWinSize
global WinSizeBuff

; 'ioctl' codes
TIOCGWINSZ equ 0x5413

; Buffers needed for procedures
WinSizeBuff db 32

section .text ; x86 assembly instructions go here

GetWinSize:
mov eax, 0x36 ; Specify `ioctl` syscall in 32-bit x86 assembly
mov ebx, STDOUT ; STDOUT file descriptor stored in ebx
mov ecx, TIOCGWINSZ ; 'ioctl' code for retrieving size of Linux Terminal
lea edx, [WinSizeBuff] ; Load address of buffer 'winsize_struct' into register 'edx'
int 0x80 ; Vector Interrupt 128 (Kernel Services Dispatcher/Syscall Dispatcher)
ret ; Return from procedure
```

File: Print.asm

```
; Author/Programmer: David Mark Serrano
; Library: Print
; Date Created: 08/26/2023
; Version: 1.0
; Purpose: To define all procedures related to printing data to text via STDOUT

section .data ; Initialized data goes here

; File descriptors for STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
STDERR equ 2

; Escape sequences used in Print.asm
Clr db `\033[2J`, 0  ; Escape sequence to clear the screen followed by null terminator
ClrLen equ $ - Clr ; Calculate the length of the message

; Global declarations for 'ClrScreen' procedure
global ClrScreen


section .text ; x86 assembly instructions go here

; This procedure (Line XX - Line XX) will clear the Linux Terminal screen
ClrScreen:
mov eax, 0x4 ; Syscall number for write
mov ebx, STDOUT ; Specify 'STDOUT' or (File Descriptor 1) as the destination for the output
mov ecx, Clr ; Pointer to 'msg'
mov edx, ClrLen  ; Length of the 'msg'
int 0x80 ; Specify Vector Interrupt 128 (Kernel Services Dispatcher / Syscall Dispatcher 
ret ; Return to main 'Battle_Chess.asm'
```

Comment: We don't need 5 paragraphs about your general situation before you get to the actual technical question.  Delete most/all of that, and any you do keep should go somewhere else (like a P.S. at the end, unless it's at most 1 sentence.)  And write a title related to order / layout of your code mattering; "strange bug" could describe almost every debugging question on the site, since if it wasn't strange to the person posting the question, they wouldn't have needed to ask someone else about it. More importantly, it tells future readers nothing; e.g. if that came up in google for their own problem.

Comment: Also, the fact that you used up 5 paragraphs of intro doesn't justify making the real part of the question all in bold.  Don't do that.  It's good that you wrote lots of details about your problem, though, so these presentation problems should be easily fixable to improve the question.

Comment: Does `strace` show the right bytes being written to the terminal even for the call-sites that don't work?  I wondered if you could be overwriting the bytes of `Clr: db ...` in memory, since you put it in the read+write `.data` section.  Otherwise maybe previous partial escape sequences could have left the terminal not ready to see the start of a new one?  IDK what the rest of your code does, it's more than I wanted to read, and not indented so it looks like a wall of code.  (See [Prime number NASM x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60683898) for good coding style)

Comment: I don't suppose the `0` byte at the end of the string could be messing anything up.  You don't need or want to write it to stdout, but it's part of your calculated length so you do.  Just remove the `,0` at the end of `Clr: db ...`, since you never use it with functions like `fputs` that want a 0-terminated C string, only with `write` that wants a pointer+length.

Comment: Without debugging this in detail, I suspect that `ClrScreen` overwrites some registers that you expect to be preserved in some places where you call the function.

Comment: Thank you all for helping out with your comments. I'll be clearing out all the unnecessary details of the question soon and I will try your solutions. Appreciate all the effort and I'll get back to this with the proper solution.

Comment: (Oops, wrong link for coding style, meant to link code-review [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965))

Comment: `blackQueen db 8` reserves 1 byte, initialized with value `0x08`.  You probably are overwriting the `Clr:` string; `Print.o` is the last object file, so its `.data` goes right after the `.data` from other object files, meaning that `mov DWORD [blackQueen + 4], imm32` can step on it.  You'd see this if you used `strace` like I suggested to see if the bytes written to stdout were still the escape sequence, and/or set a watchpoint in GDB on those bytes to see if anything modified them.  And you'll see that putting the data somewhere else, like in `.rodata`, will change the symptoms of your bug.

Comment: You want `dq 0` to reserve 64 bits (8 bytes).  You can put it in `.bss` as `resb 8` or `resq 1`.  (You could put the initial conditions in `.rodata` to efficiently copy from when restarting a game,  with `rep movsb` memcpy, or `movaps` 16-byte load/store instead of 2x mov-immediate per qword).  Or for a single game, use correct non-zero initializers in `.data`, like `WhitePawns: resq 0x000000000000FF00`, and remove the instructions that store to them on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`blackQueen db 8` reserves 1 byte, initialized with value `0x08`.**

You're running instructions that store past the end of the space you actually reserved in `.data`, stepping on the `Clr:` string, so when you `write` it to stdout you aren't writing the bytes of an ANSI escape sequence.

`Print.o` is the last object file, so its `.data` goes right after the `.data` from other object files, meaning that `mov DWORD [blackQueen + 4], imm32` can step on it.

You can see this if you use `strace` like I suggested to see if the bytes written to stdout were still the escape sequence, and/or set a watchpoint in GDB on those bytes to see if anything modified them.

You'll also see that putting `Clr` somewhere else, like in `section .rodata` where it belongs, will make your program still clear the screen on any call.  (It won't fix the bug with your program not having reserved enough space in `.data` for its bitboards though, which will be a showstopper once you do anything with them, since stores to the earlier ones will step on later ones.)

---

**You want `dq 0` to reserve 64 bits (8 bytes)**.

Or better, you can put your bitboards from `whitePawns` to `blackKing` in `.bss` as `resb 8` or `resq 1` for each.  ("reserve" pseudo-instructions take a number of elements to reserve, unlike `dd` = "data dword" or "define dword" which takes a list of values).

You could put the initial conditions in `.rodata` to efficiently copy from when restarting a game,  with `rep movsb` as a simple memcpy, or `movaps` 16-byte load/store instead of 2x mov-immediate per qword.

Or for a single game, use correct non-zero initializers in `.data`, like `WhitePawns: dq 0x000000000000FF00`, and remove the instructions that store to them on startup.

---

Related:

- [How to create a variable in the BSS section in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909823/how-to-create-a-variable-in-the-bss-section-in-nasm)
- [Which variable size to use (db, dw, dd) with x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168743/which-variable-size-to-use-db-dw-dd-with-x86-assembly)
- [How do labels and dd declarations work in NASM? What's the C equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453482/how-do-labels-and-dd-declarations-work-in-nasm-whats-the-c-equivalent)